# How to.. Get the sum of the checked row for the the values "value" checked in AngularJS + HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

​I'm a newbie when it comes to Angular, but, I really want to improve myself and learn, butttt now I have a big big problem.

I don't know how to get the sum for every row I checked ..only for the value entity.

Here you have a plunker with my try code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/iBdEtQU1gPrCSxXQ2yyW?p=preview

Thanks alot !

View HTML:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody ng-repeat= "values in getSelected()">
    <td></td>
    <td>{{values.id}}</td>
    <td>{{values.name}}</td>
    <td>{{values.address}}</td>
    <td>{{values.value}}</td>
    </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Controller code:

```
     $scope.employees = [
       { id:"1", name: "A",              address: "A1", value:10},
       { id:"2", name: "B",            address: "A2",value:15 },
       { id:"3", name: "C",            address: "A3",value:20},
       { id:"4", name: "D",             address: "A4",value:25 },
       { id:"5", name: "E",             address: "A5" ,value:30},
     ]

     $scope.getSelected = function () {
       var ar = $scope.employees.filter(function (value) {
          if (value.checked == 1) {
            return true;
          } else {
           return false;
          }
       });    
       console.log(ar);
       return ar;
     };
```

Comment: Why don't you just calculate the value into a new variable? 
Also please add the related code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the sum of values of all selected rows. You may iterate over the array of selected items and sum up the values:

```
function() {
  return $scope.getSelected().reduce((sum, item) => {
    return sum + item.value;
  }, 0);
}
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/TKDuKQB4rFO5U6w0bEBl?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very very much ! I don't have words to describe the happiness I feel right now. I try to learn on my own to code and I was stuck in this problem for a while. You saved me! I'm dumb,stupid, etc,  I now, but i'm ambitious :)).